# Registration Process look strange in Android Application

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to debug an android application. In registration process, I just need a phone number. I have a source code looked like below:

```
private void handleRegistrationIntent(Intent intent) {
    markAsVerifying(true);
    Log.w("RegistrationService","State change to handleRegistrationIntent");

    AccountCreationSocket socket = null;
    String number                = intent.getStringExtra("e164number");

try {
    String password = Util.getSecret(18);
    String key      = Util.getSecret(40);

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor                 = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Constants.PASSWORD_PREFERENCE, password);
    editor.putString(Constants.KEY_PREFERENCE, key);
    editor.commit();

    initializeChallengeListener();

    setState(new RegistrationState(RegistrationState.STATE_CONNECTING, number));
    Log.w("RegistrationService", "State change to STATE_CONNECTING");
    System.out.println(number);
    socket = new AccountCreationSocket(this, number, password);
    socket.createAccount(false);
    socket.close();

    setState(new RegistrationState(RegistrationState.STATE_VERIFYING_SMS, number));
    Log.w("RegistrationService", "State change to STATE_VERIFYING_SMS");
    String challenge = waitForChallenge();
    socket           = new AccountCreationSocket(this, number, password);
    socket.verifyAccount(challenge, key);
```

In Logcat Android, I get this log:

> 12-11 10:49:12.561 7769-7769/com.qepon W/RegistrationProgress: State change to handleStateIdle
>
> 12-11 10:49:12.611 7769-7769/com.apps I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1a8792e8 time:10508674
>
> 12-11 10:49:12.611 7769-8779/com.apps W/RegistrationService: State change to handleRegistrationIntent
>
> 12-11 10:49:12.651 7769-8779/com.apps W/RegistrationService: State change to STATE_CONNECTING
>
> 12-11 10:49:12.651 7769-8779/com.apps I/System.out: +62898xxxxxxx

It's over. In GUI, I received an error: Can't connect to the network, but i can use browsing with my smartphone. Beside that, I don't get an error or something wrong in the server.
I'm confused what is the problem of this application. Can anyone help me please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the permission for your application to access the internet in the `androidManifest.xml` file using the `android.pemission.INTERNET`?

Comment: Yes, I have added android.permission.INTERNET in androidManifest.xml = <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />